# Creating a new comment only works once

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-core

I created a method for posting comments on a post. Everything works fine when I first post a comment. It appears under the post, it's saved in the database etc. However, if I want to create a second comment right away (without refreshing the page- because this way it does work) I get this error:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update: Error: An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'JoyAndFaithLicenta.Data.DataContext'.
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details.
 ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'AspNetUsers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>b__169_0(Task`1 result)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationResultTaskFromResultTask`2.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<.cctor>b__274_0(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ExecuteWithThreadLocal(Task& currentTaskSlot, Thread threadPoolThread)

at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync
(IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(IEnumerable`1 commandBatches, IRelationalConnection connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IList`1 entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(DbContext _, Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at 
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at JoyAndFaithLicenta.Data.UserRepository.SaveAllAsync() in C:\Users\Georgia\source\repos\JoyAndFaithLicenta\JoyAndFaithLicenta\Data\UserRepository.cs:line 84 at JoyAndFaithLicenta.Helpers.LogUserActivity.OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next) in C:\Users\Georgia\source\repos\JoyAndFaithLicenta\JoyAndFaithLicenta\Helpers\LogUserActivity.cs:line 30 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeNextResourceFilter>g__Awaited|24_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|19_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger) at 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) at JoyAndFaithLicenta.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context) in C:\Users\Georgia\source\repos\JoyAndFaithLicenta\JoyAndFaithLicenta\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 33
```

Why is that? It's the only functionality where I have this problem. However, every other functionality has a `SaveAsync()` method created in the repository, and I have not created a repository for the comments, so I'm using DataContext: `_context.SaveChangesAsync()`.

This is the method for posting a comment:

```
[HttpPost("create/{postId}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<CommentDto>> PostComment(CommentDto commentDto, int postId)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest("Not a valid model");
    var user = await _userRepository.GetUserByUsernameAsync(User.GetUsername());

    var comment = new Comment
    {
        PostId = postId,
        UserId = user.Id,
        Text = commentDto.Text,
        Created = commentDto.Created,
        User = commentDto.User
    };

    _context.Comments.Add(comment);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return new CommentDto
    {
        PostId = comment.PostId,
        UserId = comment.UserId,
        Text = comment.Text,
        Created = comment.Created,
        User = comment.User
    };
}
```

And this is the comment entity:

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int? PostId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to post the error. You posted only the call stack. Is it a constraint violation? A concurrency conflict? Something else? How is `Comment`'s ID generated? An auto-generated IDENTITY wouldn't need any kind of refresh. A MAX+1 would (and create a ton of other problems as well)

Comment: I have no idea. That's all I'm receiving while debugging. If it's of any use, the user entity contains a list of comments, and the post entity also contains a list of comments. It crashes on this line: `_context.Comments.Add(comment);`

Comment: The comment's id is a random number, but usually the first id is 1 and the others will be incremented by 1 each time. I have no extra logic for this. Also, if I create a comment, delete it and then create a new one I get the same error.

Comment: Post the full exception text. You didn't mention any error, either in the title or question

Comment: `The comment's id is a random number, but usually the first id is 1 and the others will be incremented by 1 each time. I have no extra logic for this.` that's guaranteed to cause duplicate IDs. Why don' you use an IDENTITY ? What is the *actual* code that generates this ID? `Random` won't return `1`, nor will it increment values. You have extra logic doing this, which will always fail after a while

Comment: You've missed the first line of the exception.

Comment: I am using Identity, but only for the users. I was refering to the id of the comment. I am not using `Random`, I just said that it's usually a random number, because I had cases where the first id was 2053 for example

Comment: I have posted the error

Comment: Is it because of the `user.Id`? Because that is where Identity is involved

Comment: How Database Context is injected? are you using singleton ?

Comment: I have a `private readonly DataContext _context;` and I'm initializing _context in the constructor.  `public CommentController(DataContext context) {  _context = context; }`

Comment: @Alessia but i mean in Services, how are you injecting that? options are f.e. `.AddDbContext()` or maybe `AddSingleton<DataContext>`

Comment: It's `.AddDbContext()`

Comment: Does it work if you don't set the `User` property on your `comment` object? You're already setting the `UserId` so you shouldn't need to set the `User` too. Given that you're setting it to `commentDto.User` (which has come from the client, not from the database) I suspect EF thinks you're trying to add another user with the same ID as the existing user.

Comment: Yes, that was it. I already commented to an answer saying that was the problem but thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your `onModelCreating` function, but i think it is caused because you have not `[Key]` in your comment id.

```
public class Comment
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string Text { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public int? PostId { get; set; }
}
```

Then database will use Id as Key, and you are sure that keys aren't repeated.

Also, i think that you are injected `DataContext` service wrong.
Try to make the same job like this:

```
using(var cnx = new DataContext()
{
var comment = new Comment
    {
        PostId = postId,
        UserId = user.Id,
        Text = commentDto.Text,
        Created = commentDto.Created,
        User = commentDto.User
    };

    cnx.Comments.Add(comment);

    await cnx.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

If it works, its probplem with your DI in Startup.cs.

Remember, the best way to inject DataContext of EntityFramework is:

```
services.AddDbContext<DataContext>();
```

Comment: I have tried this, but it doesn't work. This is the model builder `b.Property<int>("Id")
   .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
    .HasColumnType("int")     .UseIdentityColumn();`. I don't have anything about comments in the onModelCreating.

Comment: This is my onModelCreating: `protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {   base.OnModelCreating(builder);
 builder.Entity<User>().HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles)
  .WithOne(u => u.User).HasForeignKey(ui => ui.UserId).IsRequired();

            builder.Entity<Role>().HasMany(ur => ur.UserRoles) .WithOne(r => r.Role).HasForeignKey(ri => ri.RoleId).IsRequired(); }`

Comment: I have made some changes in my answer.

Comment: This is exactly how I am injecting it. And it also works for the rest of the functionalities. I think there's a problem with the comments only maybe?

Comment: Solved it, I was adding the user when creating the comment, but I only need the UserId. That's what caused the error.

Answer (score 0):

According to below code

```
 var comment = new Comment
{
    PostId = postId,
    UserId = user.Id,
    Text = commentDto.Text,
    Created = commentDto.Created,
    User = commentDto.User
};
```

You are trying to insert a new User as well. Since you are trying to create a new user with assigned ID you are getting this error. Because Aspnetuser table does not allow to pass ID explicitly since  IDENTITY_INSERT is set to false by default.

I am not sure why you want to insert a user as well along with comment. Probably it can be a requirement. If you really want to create a user, then your User object should not have a assigned ID value.

If this is by mistake change User to UserId.

Comment: Yes, I have already solved the issue by deleting that line with the new User. I commented this on another answer. However, thanks a lot for answering!